# Converting program to function

Tags: python, function, variables

I'm trying to convert a python program to a function. I'm not quite grasping what I'm doing wrong. I've had a look at how to write functions but it's not clicking. What I'm having difficulty understanding is:

1. can any python code be turned into a function by just adding the function statement, call and arguments or is there more to it?
2. When should an argument be used as opposed to just calling the function
3. Declaring variables in a function, take my code below as an example. where should number_list be declared in a function compared to where I declare it in the non-function code?

Here's the non function that works fine:

```
import random##importing random module

number_list = []
total = 0 ##starts as 0 and increases with generated random number 

for i in range(5):###running a loop- set to five for 5 list items 
  random_num = random.randint(1, 100)##using randint() to return an integer number selected element from the specified range in this case 1-100
  total = total + random_num##setting value for total with random number 
  number_list.append(random_num)##adds to the end of the list 


print('The numbers generated were:' , end=",")
for i in range(5): ##number of list items 
    print(number_list[i], end=",")
print('The largest number is: ', max(number_list))##Using max() method to print largest element of the list 
print('The sum of the numbers is: ', total)
```

And the function I've made so far that gives an error variable number_list/total/random not declared:

```
number_list = []
total = 0
random = 0
def randomsum(number_list,total):
  number_list = []
  total = 0 ##starts as 0 and increases with generated random number 

  for i in range(5):###running a loop- set to five for 5 list items 
    random_num = random.randint(1, 100)##using randint() to return an integer number selected element from the specified range in this case 1-100
    total = total + random_num##setting value for total with random number 
    number_list.append(random_num)##adds to the end of the list 


  print('The numbers generated were:' , end=",")
  for i in range(5): ##number of list items 
    print(number_list[i], end=",")

randomsum(number_list,total)
print('The largest number is: ', max(number_list))##Using max() method to print largest element of the list 
print('The sum of the numbers is: ', total)
```

Also are there any good Youtube videos about this? I've had a look but not finding the right videos.

Comment: Start looking at books and documentation, instead of videos :) . Learn about local variables and function parameters, to begin with.

Comment: Yes, any code can be put inside a function, as long as you pass as parameters any extra data that you need from "outside" and that you want to use to change the behavior of the computation, and declare as local variables the things that are internal, specific to the function (for example, the list that you intend to return or the total counter)

Comment: Good to know, thank you. I guess videos are good for me because I'm a visual learner but I see what you're saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
import random

def randomsum():
    # usually it is a good idea to declare the variables locally
    number_list = []
    total = 0
    for i in range(5):
        random_num = random.randint(1, 100)
        total = total + random_num
        number_list.append(random_num)

    print('The numbers generated were:', end=",")
    for i in range(5):
        print(number_list[i], end=",")
    #and then return them so that they can be retrieved by the function caller
    return total, number_list


total, number_list = randomsum()
#this way makes for a bit cleaner code than using global variables.
print('The largest number is: ', max(number_list)) 
print('The sum of the numbers is: ', total)
```

However I have to agree with @Oscar that you should take a good look at the basics:-).

As for your questions:

1. Yes. And no. Yes, it is possible to convert any python code into a function(as in any reasonable programming language). However it is not always straightforward because of parameters, return values retrieval and scoping.
2. Parameters and return values are usually the preferred way as opposed to global variables.
3. For ones that will be used extensively the place is usually right after the function declaration. However in python there are no strict rules and you can declare variables wherever. Beware though, here be dragons.

Comment: I didn't realize you could do 
```total, number_list = randomsum()```

What about if you had arguments in the function like def randomsum(total, number_list): ?

Comment: That is a completely different use case - you would be passing parameters to the function. Number_list is an array and would be passed as a reference, while the total is a number and gets passed by value. Hilarity ensues